# How to get column names from a large file by using python dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I have a very huge tsv file. It is about 1GB. I just want to create an array that contains column names. This is what I've done so far:

```
import pandas as pd 

x = pd.read_csv('mytsvfile.tsv', nrows=1).columns
```

Unfortunatelly, this gives me

```
>>> type(x)
<class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'>
```

and when I convert it to list, the length of list is 1 which is not equal to number of columns I have in tsv file

Comment: What is separator?

Comment: @jezrael nice! when I add '\t' as sep, problem solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need add separator (`\t` if tab) and also `nrows=0` works:

```
x = pd.read_csv('mytsvfile.tsv', nrows=0, sep='\t').columns.tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the column names, and the column names are in the first line, and you need it in a python list format, why bring pandas into the mix at all? Just use `readline`() like so:

```
with open('mytsvfile.tsv', 'r') as tsv:
  Columns=tsv.readline().split('\t')
```

Sorry about the tab character, I'm on mobile.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but, the column names is only one of the things I need from the table. Later I have to work with other parts of it too.

Comment: @zwlayer what's the rough dimensions of this table? What's the data filled with? If you can help me see your use case maybe we can get a better method

Answer (score 0):

what you are looking for can be obtained without any intermediate:

```
list_of_column_names=list(x)
```

more generally:

```
list(df.columns)
```

you can also determine the number of columns of your dataframe `df`:

```
df.columns.nunique()
```